# Mapping xml tags by Rule Learning/Generation Algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, association-rules

I'm trying to map tags/attributes from xml files from different sources. I've found a paper called [Semantic Mapping of XML Tags using Inductive Machine Learning](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2520270_Semantic_Mapping_of_XML_Tags_using_Inductive_Machine_Learning?enrichId=rgreq-5b2cac5993ee9c786bd3203650c98216-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzI1MjAyNzA7QVM6MTAyNzcyNTAyNDMzODA5QDE0MDE1MTQyODI4MzM%3D&el=1_x_3&_esc=publicationCoverPdf).

Among various things, it also talks about a Rule Generation Algorithm called [Data Squeezer](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YvTxwaLJJ2kC&pg=PA394&lpg=PA394&dq=data%20reduction%20via%20prototypical%20concept%20learning&source=bl&ots=lYaHb2xgMG&sig=VsIwE5-T4H1gMfJ0RV9sDThbtlw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ0LDu9LvRAhWMtY8KHRyXDxQQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=data%20reduction%20via%20prototypical%20concept%20learning&f=false).
However, I'm wondering what other (better) algorithms can be used for deep learning xml tags.

Also do we have any such algorithm implemented in [TensorFlow](http://tensorflow.org/) or any other open source library ?